# How to toggle button on and off with gpiozero?

Tags: python, pi-3b+, gpiozero

> Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

I can't seem to find a solution of doing this using gpiozero. I've done it using rpi.gpio with add_event_detect and call back to change state but I was under the impression gpiozero is much simpler.

This link https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/physical-computing/9 basically says a switch would turn the led on with a pressed and release then turn is off with another pressed and release but doesn't actually show how to do this.

```
from gpio import LEDBoard, Button

button = Button(5, pull_up=True, bounce_time=200)
leds = LEDBoard(26, 19, 13, 6)

def on():
leds.on()
print('On...')

def off():
leds.off()
print('off...')

button.when_pressed = on
button.when_released = off
```

It doesn't even turn off when released. Is that due to the pull_up = True?
I thought this code would turn it on when pressed and off when released but it just turns on and stays on.

TIA!

Comment: You are asking us to guess how your button is wired up.

Comment: @joan Oh, I'm sorry! didn't think it was relevent. Honestly thought this was just a python issue. The button is connected to ground pin and gpio5 pin, leds are connected to ground and 4 gpio pins.

Comment: ...and by gpio5 pin you mean pin 29? See https://pinout.xyz/

Comment: @joan Apologies, I meant BCM 5 not pin 5! Ok. Do you have everything you need to help me now? :)

Comment: In that configuration the button will normally read high (1) because of the pull-up to 3V3.  When you press the button it is connected to ground and the button will read low (0).  When you release the button it will again read high.

Comment: So should I connect to 3v3 pin and not ground so it reads high when pushed? or can I just set it to high is off and low is on and keep it in ground? Thanks Joan!

Comment: I would connect one end to 3V3 and the other to the GPIO with a pull-down rather than a pull-up.  That is a more natural way for most of us although I think electronics guys are quite happy either way.

Comment: Ok, so I did that. It only works now it is `pull_up = False` but again it turns the leds on and stays on. So essentially its doing the same thing.

Comment: In a terminal window run the following to monitor the GPIO level changes.  `sudo pigpiod` then `./monitor.py` where monitor.py is from http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py

Comment: @joan: "No such file or directory"

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> How to toggle a button ... ?

***Answer***

Well, the OP's "question" is not a question，so I can give no answer.  But I can explain why the OP's "question" is not a question.

> 1. A human can press a button and then release the button.  This is not a "toggle".  Let us say if the human presses button and then releases, and
>      after some time, the human presses the button again and releases. Now
>      there are two sequences of press event and release event, or if you
>      like, one sequence of four events: press, release, press, release. No "toggling" happened ever.
> 2. Now the LED.  Python can "toggle" a LED, ie, if the LED is on, then turn it off, and vice versa.  This is the meaning of "toggling" a
>      LED.

In other words, python can toggle a LED, but never a button, because only a human can change the status of a button: being pressed, being released.  I know it is confusing. Perhaps a picture helps.

[image: led toggle]

The picture below tells (1) how to toggle LED, and (2) how to read button.

[image: button and led]

Comment: @tifong01: Ok. My terminology has been a bit off. I meant how do I turn a button into a switch? So I need 2 sequences to turn it off and on. Can you help me? the picture didn't help. `button.wait_for_press()` then `led.toggle` `sleep(0.5)`. `button.wait_for_press()` `led.off(). That just turns the Leds on and they stay on. At the very least it should toggle?

Comment: Well,let you show you a switch.

Comment: I have shown the led and button picture.  See you tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking to have the LED on when the button is pressed and off when the button is unpressed? If so, [this section from the gpiozero docs](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#button-controlled-led) explains how to do so:

"Turn on an LED when a Button is pressed:

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button 
from signal import pause 

led = LED(17) 
button = Button(2)

button.when_pressed = led.on
button.when_released = led.off 

pause()
```

Alternatively:

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button 
from signal import pause 

led = LED(17) 
button = Button(2) 

led.source = button 

pause()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a toggle function in GPIO zero.
So if you want a single LED on pin 26 to change state every time a button on pin 5 is pressed:

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button
from time import sleep

led = LED(26)
button = Button(5)

while True:
    if button.is_pressed:
        led.toggle()
        sleep(0.5)
```

(The sleep is needed, otherwise it changes state while you're pressing the button, and all you get is a strobing LED when you push the button)

Answer (score 0):

> I meant how do I turn a button into a switch?

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button

led = LED(25)
button = Button(2)

while True : # otherwise the script will only work once
        button.wait_for_press()
        led.toggle()
        button.wait_for_release()
```

> So I need 2 sequences to turn it off and on

Example 1: toggle state with functions (stays on or off)

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button

led = LED(25) # GPIO 25
ledState= 0
button = Button(2) # GPIO 2

def on():
    led.on() # Since Python doesn't have function-enclosing parentheses, here are 4 spacebars to assign the contents to the function.

def off():
    led.off()


while True : # otherwise the script will only work once
        button.wait_for_press()
        if ledState == 0:
            on()
            ledState = 1
            button.wait_for_release()   # wait or otherwise the script will trigger again while the button is still pressed
            continue        # stop the current loop iteration here and start again
        if ledState == 1:   # alternative: if not ledState == 0: or else: 
             off()
             ledState = 0
             button.wait_for_release()
```

Example 2: toggle state with functions (led is on, only while button is pressed)

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button

led = LED(25) # GPIO 25
ledState= 0
button = Button(2) # GPIO 2

def on():
    led.on() # Since Python doesn't have function-enclosing parentheses, here are 4 spacebars to assign the contents to the function.

def off():
    led.off()


while True : # otherwise the script will only work once
    button.wait_for_press()
    on()
    button.wait_for_release()
    off()
```

Example 3 using functions and "when_pressed" && "when_released"

Useful link: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button
from signal import pause

led = LED(25) # GPIO 25
button = Button(2) # GPIO 2

def on():
    led.on() # Since Python doesn't have function-enclosing parentheses, here are 4 spacebars to assign the contents to the function.

def off():
    led.off()

button.when_pressed = on # Contrary to expectations, there should be no parentheses after the function call
button.when_released = off

pause() # prevents the script from stopping after it read through everything. The pause function enables the script to keep on listening for button presses
```